# How to manage execution order of Monitor.Enter

Tags: c#, threadpool

I use ThreadPool to perform simultaneous operations. Each operation is performed successfully. I also lock that operations via Monitor.Enter method because if I don't do that I have a thread collision problem. The problem is that after running my application I see that the operations are performed in wrong order. Here is my code:

```
using System.Threading;

private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

public void Test()
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list1.Add(i);

    int toProcess = list1.Count;

    using (ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            var idx = i;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
                {
                    WriteToConsole(list1[idx]);

                    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                        resetEvent.Set();

                }), null);
        }

        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void WriteToConsole(int p)
{
    bool lockWasTaken = false;
    var temp = obj;

    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);

    Console.Write(p.ToString());

    Monitor.Exit(temp);
}
```

### Output:

0
1
2
3
7
5
9
6
4
8

What should I do to fix that wrong order?

Thanks

Comment: Nasty habit to do not include `using` to the code. Newbies may have troubles.

Comment: This is actually *intentional*.  It solves a threading problem called "locking convoys".  Backgrounder [is here](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/).  Long story short, if you require ordering then you have to take care of it yourself by adding the required synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do to fix that wrong order?

Nothing. It's supposed to be like that. When you process items in parallel the order of execution is generally not guaranteed. So your options are:

- Do work sequentially
- Sort results after parallel execution
- Don't bother with order at all

Answer (score 1):

If you do it ordered, it inherently means that you're processing it sequentially. When you want it to be done sequentially, you don't need threads at all.

That said, You don't have to deal with threadpool directly anymore. Use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Then you can use `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll` to wait for its completion.

Also your `WriteToConsole` method is superfluous. `Console.Write` access doesn't need to be locked as it is already thread-safe. It could be simply written as

```
private void WriteToConsole(int p)
{    
    Console.Write(p);    
}
```

Comment: I don't use Console.Write normally. It was used to show an example. Thanks.

Comment: @OrkunBekar But if you're using `Console.Write` no synchronization needed.